# How do you set About menu title in Oracle AppBundler for OSX?

Tags: java, macos, packaging

I am using [Oracle AppBundler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html) to allow me package JRE inside an OSX *.app. But I can't seems to set its About menu to my liking, as shown below.

[image: Unable to set the About menu]

The about menu still display the main class name. This is part of my `build.xml`. Any idea of what might cause this?

```
 <target name="bundle">
    <bundleapp outputdirectory="dist"
        name="My Name is emaN"
        displayname="My Name is emaN"
        identifier="My Name is emaN"
        mainclassname="test.java.TestJava"
        icon="auxes/icon.icns">
        <runtime dir="${env.JAVA_HOME}" />
        <classpath file="lib/test-java.jar"/>
        <option value="-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true"/>
        <option value="-Dcom.apple.macos.useScreenMenuBar=true"/>
        <option value="-Dcom.apple.mrj.application.apple.menu.about.name=My Name is emaN"/>
    </bundleapp>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001909-212952-TPXREF134). Just supply `-Xdock:name=Your Liking` into AppBundler JVM Options.